# What is "[ ]" sign in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to find an answer for it but nothing found...
In the simple below codes:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [] );
```

I have never seen an example using "[ ]" sign. What is it for?

Comment: Simply an empty array when no dependencies needed.

Comment: I guess you should first take a look at what JavaScript is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the `dependencies` array you want this module depend on.

So if you need a routing system you would say something like so:

```
angular.module("app.module", ["ui.router"]);
```

This says `app.module` **depends** on `ui.router` for its routing.

Your example above is simply declaring an `angular module` with **no dependencies** and assign it to the variable `app`.

Answer (score 1):

**Example: -**

```
var navigation = angular.module('navigation',[]); // a sample module in angular.

//now creating a module called myapp. I can use navigation module in myapp as below

var myApp = angular.module('myapp',**['navigation']**); // here myApp module uses navigation module.
```

if myapp need no dependency use empty array as below.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',**[ ]**);// pass emty array when **no dependency**.
```